# Classic ASP - It’s totally outdated but is it irrelevant?

Tags: asp-classic

Although I develop all of my company’s web-sites in .net, all of my personal sites are still in "Classic ASP". I'm always being pressured to move away from it... but it works! Why change?

Comment: "Irreverent" means "showing a lack of respect". ASP Classic is certainly not irreverent!

Comment: I don't know if it is really "irreverent" - I wouldn't have thought it was even disrespectful

Comment: Seriously now -- who is pressuring you, and why?  This sounds like a human relations problem, not a technical problem.

Comment: Did you mean irrelevant instead of irreverent? If you really meant irreverent, you'll have to excuse my English. I've never seen word used in that context.

Comment: Thanks for the fix! I do that all the time!!

Comment: Classic ASP is not irrelevant. It is part of the web as everything else is. Though, it should not be used when creating a new project. Check ajaxed.org which is a free recent rapid development lib for classic asp. Very useful if u need to maintain legacy apps

Comment: my bank still uses asp the online banking front-end, why? it just works, transition to new technology just for the heck of it isn't a good goal...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are some reasons to change but in the end, if your sites are up and running and you don't really need the new stuff, stick with it.

One good reason to change is existing support from MS and the developers community. I guess is harder to get a answer for a problem with ASP since most people moved to .net long ago.

Comment: Honestly, I agree - it's almost impossible to sort through all the .NET documentation online to find the classic ASP stuff. It’s near crippling!

Answer (score 4):

The only real reason would be because the technology is getting to the point where you're going to find yourself without a platform to run your code on.

...who knows how much longer Microsoft is going to keep Classic ASP support in IIS.

Comment: You'll always have VM, however, to run an old OS with and old version of IIS.

Comment: But how many hosting providers are going to let you run a VM with an unsupported OS on it?

Answer (score 3):

In general, I'd never upgrade working code just for the heck of it because it's in an older, deprecated language. Especially for something like a personal page.

I can think of one exception, though: are you currently in the job market?  You probably don't want to give clients/employers the impression that you're stuck in Classic ASP land.

I have a lot of Classic ASP production code, though, and I feel you on the Classic ASP "backlash."   It's actually kind of embarassing to have that .asp extension in your URLs.  I've actually considered changing the extension on all the .asp files to something new and changing IIS' settings so that new extension is handled by the ASP component.

Comment: Definitely not in the job market - I point prospective employers to other company’s sites that I’ve worked on - never my own (Unless its to look at some of my C++ code).

Answer (score 3):

I was in a similar situation - working on .NET at the office, and 5 or 6 sites at home on ASP that worked fine. For me the compelling reason to switch was when the .NET MVC community preview was released. I had been working with other MVC frameworks for years and was glad to be able to use a well-built native MS one.

I have switched about 4 ASP sites over to MVC as a way to learn the new framework and I am really glad I did. I'll always have a soft spot for ASP (and can still remember enough to answer most questions), but .NET MVC feels so much more advanced.

Comment: Advanced & extendable! Very true!

Answer (score 2):

If you feel your skills with what you do at your job is fine (don't need more practice) and you are happy with your personal sites the way they are then leave it.

The only thought to consider is if you were to want to use the personal sites as a way to promote yourself it could be viewed as old tech and thus your skills may be looked down upon.

Answer (score 2):

It is outdate? absolutely, but is it Irrelevant? well it is based on scope of your application, if it is just a simple database driven (eg: CMS, e-commerce) i personally think that classic asp still relevant for that, in fact that I still use it for some CMS/e-commerce projects since I already have application legacy written with it and has satisfied my clients for years.

but if you going to build large business application with multi programmers involved then you may need to think about .NET

Answer (score 1):

For me personally, ASP.NET has been more reliable.  I mean, some bad ASP.NET code can't as easily take down IIS as some bad ASP code.  Again, that's just from my own experiences.  I don't know how much merit there is to it.

But I don't see the harm in running your personal sites in classic ASP really as long as it's working for you.

Answer (score 1):

Classic ASP certainly isn't as common now as it was before the introduction of the .NET family, but I don't think you're hurting yourself much by maintaining personal sites in it. If you were self-employed and looking for work as a .NET developer, it might be odd to have personal sites only in Classic ASP; in that situation, you could convert one or more to .NET, and that might help you demonstrate your skills in both sets of languages.